# Checking for whitespace in a string typed array - Swift

Tags: swift

In a string typed array how can I achieve the functionality as I would for checking whitespace in a string? I'd like to check if the array contains only whitespace

```
 var stringExample: String!
 var stringArrayExample: [String]!

 if stringExample.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty{
 //string contains whitespace characters
 }
```

Comment: Be aware that `trimmingCharacters` removes characters from the passed character set *only* at the beginning and end of the string, not within a string.

Comment: what do you want exactly? Know if a string array contains only whitespace strings? Or if it contains 1 or more whitespace strings?

Comment: yes I updated my question, if the array contains only whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 3 would look something like this if I'm understanding what you're wanting:

```
var someStrings = ["   ", "foo", "bar", "\t"]

let result = someStrings.filter { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty }

print(result) // ["   ", "\t"]
```

If you're just wanting to know if the array of strings are *all* whitespace-only strings you could change the last two lines to:

```
let result = someStrings.filter { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty == false }

print(result.isEmpty) // false
```

Note that both these use `.whitespacesAndNewlines` if you don't want new lines, just use `.whitespaces` like you do in your original example.

Comment: yes this is what I needed, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: For the second case you don't need `.filter`, you can simply check `.contains` with the same expression.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension for `String` which returns whether it's empty or contains only whitespace:

```
extension String {
    var isEmptyOrWhitespace : Bool {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty
    }
}
```

And since I'm also a .NET developer and like the methods `Any`, `All` etc. I've also created an extension for the `Array` type, which lets me check a condition for every element in the array, leveraging the `reduce` function:

```
extension Array {
    func all(test: (Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        return self.reduce(true) { $0 && test($1) }
    }
}
```

Then you can combine these two to get a fairly nice syntax, which is also fairly performant, since it "breaks" when it stumbles upon an element that does not comply with the provided test (using a `for` instead of `reduce` would probably be even more efficient).

```
let strings1 = ["   ", "", "\t"]
print(strings1.all { $0.isEmptyOrWhitespace })  // true
print(strings1.all { !$0.isEmptyOrWhitespace }) // false
```

By printing within the test, you can see it no longer executes the tests for elements when it finds the first non-compliant one.

```
let strings2 = ["   ", "x", "\t"]
print(strings2.all(test: { (str) -> Bool in
    let e = str.isEmptyOrWhitespace
    print ("[\(str)]: \(e)")
    return e
}))
```

Prints:

```
[   ]: true
[x]: false
false
```